# SQL backup with password

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup

I tried to backup database using the following script:

```
BACKUP DATABASE Northwind 
TO DISK='C:\Northwind.BAK' 
WITH MEDIAPASSWORD='my_password'
```

but I get this error :

> One or more of the options (mediapassword) are not supported for this statement. Review the documentation for supported options.

Comment: You can try to https://sqlbak.com to make scheduled backups with passwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [check the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) (as the error message suggests), then you'd see:

> Security
>
> Beginning with **SQL Server 2012**, the PASSWORD and MEDIAPASSWORD options are **discontinued** for creating backups. It is still possible to restore backups created with passwords.

Comment: So how can I secure my backup

Comment: @RaedAlsaleh: put it on a safe disk / server where no unauthorized people have access to ....

Comment: I think it was a handy feature, what is your opinion